# Custom secure page tab url so as to provide different iframe to each page tab for different page

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created an app on facebook developer account and need to provide custom iframe to each page tab of the pages. I have no clue how to do that.

I simple words, I need to provide different url (depending upon certain parameters) for iframe of page tab of each page that have installed my app (NOT MY SECURE PAGE TAB URL).

The default iframe url that will be loaded if someone installs my app is the one that I have mentioned in my SECURE PAGE TAB URL field. But I need to provide a different iframe url depending upon certain conditions. So, not my secure page tab url.
How to do that?

Comment: Different URLs are not possible; instead, you get the page id from the `signed_request`, and decide based upon that which content to display. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#integrating, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request

Comment: Thanks @CBroe But then how does the storefrontsocial.com or ecwid.com do that? They provide different iframe to their customers in their pages (Their customer's ecommerce store url) with the same app and same secure_page_tab_url.

Comment: @CBroe Still waiting for your valuable response.

Comment: Then they are probably redirecting to that target URL after they checked the page id …

Comment: Ok I got to know that I can customize the iframe url through app_data. I am using facebook node sdk for all the functionalities. How do I send app_data or get the signed request in response? https://github.com/node-facebook/facebook-node-sdk

Comment: app_data would have to be part of the URL to begin with. It is for explicitly _linking_ to page tabs from the outside, and passing data on to them while doing so. / https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#parsingsr